# Google Login in Salesforce1 App Disallow Useragent iOS

Tags: oauth, ios, google

We used to be able to use the mobile app for iOS without a problem. Now if we go to log in and click the Google Login button, the immediate message is a 403 disallowed_useragent message.

Logging in with Google on desktop works fine. Also tried logging in through Safari iOS and that authenticated fine as well.

Not sure if StackExchange community is the best place to post this but since it's the primary Salesforce iOS app, I'm sure others may have experienced this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer my own question, this is a two part process that first involves:

1. setting Use the native browser for user authentication on iOS
2. Then in the iOS app click the gear symbol in the top right corner of the log in page and add a new environment which should be your Salesforce instance ("example.my.salesforce.com"). Name it and then click on that to use that to log in. Now the Google Login should work fine without the disallow message showing.